# Planet Orbit in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

A single planet orbits a sun. With Newton's classical gravity formula, sun moves in a ellipse, with the gravity force always pointing toward the focus/sun.

With General Relativity model, how does the GR gravity force vector differ from the Newtonian gravity force? Is there a picture somewhere showing the difference?

With GR model, what is difference between the sun rotating (like our real Sun) and sun fixed?

Comment: More on [Mercury's precession in GR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+mercury+%5Bgr%5D).

Answer (score 3):

In general relativity, freely falling particles will move along geodesics, and so in order to find the path $x^\mu(s)$ followed by some particle in a space-time, we have to solve the geodesic equations,

$$\frac{\mathrm d^2x^\mu(s)}{\mathrm ds^2} = - \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\mathrm dx^\alpha(s)}{\mathrm ds}\frac{\mathrm dx^\beta(s)}{\mathrm ds}.$$

To make a connection to Newtonian gravity, depending on the solution to Einstein's field equations, it may be possible to obtain an *effective* potential from the metric tensor. For Schwarzschild,

$$V_{\mathrm{eff}} = \frac{1}{2r^2}\left(\frac{GM}{c^2}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2} \right) - \frac{GM}{r}.$$

from which you can then find the vector field, as in standard mechanics, $\vec F = -\nabla V$. As for your other question, the difference between a stationary sun and a rotating sun is that the former is then described by the Schwarzschild metric, whilst the other, by the Kerr metric.

Returning the concept of an effective potential, rather than the one above, we might want to approximate a rotating spherical body with,

$$V_{\mathrm{eff}} = \frac{1}{(a^2+r^2)^2-a^2\Delta} \left\{ aL(a^2+r^2-\Delta) + \sqrt{r^2\Delta \left[L^2r^2+M^2\left((a^2+r^2)^2-a^2\Delta)\right) \right]}\right\}$$

where $a = J/Mc$ and $\Delta = r^2 - 2GMr/c^2 + a^2$. As you can see adding in rotation significantly complicates the effective potential. For its orbits, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2959).

[image]

There's a lot to read in the paper, but this is a plot of $V_{\mathrm{eff}}$ for varying radius $r$ and $L$. The unstable and stable orbits correspond to maxima and minima. Circulator orbits are solid curves.

Comment: It'd be better if your answer had all terms defined, as otherwise the reader must go to the reference (in which case just post the reference) or start guessing what some terms may mean. I recognize J as angular momentum, but can't be sure what L, m or a are. It also would be good if you stated if the effective potential is an approximation, and if so for what conditions. I'd guess that for Schwarzchild it is highly relativistic orbits near a neutron star (nonrotating) there's more terms. Good for people to know when/if an approximation may break down and when it applies well enough.

Comment: @BobBee Using the word 'effective' implies it is an approximation; in QFT it has a definitive technical definition and in other fields still signifies some sort of approximation. I'll expand on what $a$ and $L$ are but it is immediately obvious what $M$ is...

Comment: You have an m and an M. Not clear what one of them is. As for effective, in QFT it means valid below certain energy levels, and those are often stated, eg, at or below the electroweak scale of a few TEV. In general relativity it'll have to do with the strength or the gravitational field or equivalently the curvature, or more practically how many Horizon radiuses away. It probably does not apply in strongly relativistic fields, and since the question was about general relativity it is important to know if the effective means just in the weak field case. He did say the Sun, so safe there.

Comment: @BobBee Oh you mean $m$ and $M$ on the plot axes? They're not particularly important in interpreting the purpose of the graph, but if one wants to know the details are in the paper, *as I encourage one to read.* I am not going to copy everything from there, I only thought I'd give a taste of the paper.

Comment: L is J?   ..........